# I want to write a spec specific macro

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to write a spec specific macro that goes something like this:

If spec 1 cast X
If spec 2 cast Y

*For example*

on frost spec cast deep freeze
on arcane spec cast arcane missiles

I really hope you can help me out here

Comment: Have you seen this? [Macro specialization modifiers?](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2794772904)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following macro

```
#showtooltip
/cast [spec:1] Deep Freeze
/cast [spec:2] Arcane Missiles
```

I came up with that after reading the following thread on the wow us forums

[Macro specialization modifiers?](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2794772904)

Here is what it looks like in the macro editor

[image: macro editor]

In frost spec the command is Deep Freeze

[image: frost spec]
*mapped the command to the **6** key*

In Arcane spec the command is Arcane Missiles

[image: Arcane spec]
*mapped the command to the **6** key*

Comment: @radical Welcome to [gaming.se]. If this solved the problem for you, consider marking your question as resolved by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Also, I think this could be done in a single line, e.g. `/cast [spec:1] Deep Freeze; [spec:2] Arcane Missiles`.